# SLOW Drupal over localhost | windows7 EasyPHP 64x

Tags: windows, performance, drupal, localhost, easyphp

I am running Drupal 7.16 on my laptop(Windows7 x64 with 6gb RAM over EasyPHP12.1).
For now the drupal running very slow!

I already try to:

1. Increase php.ini `realpath_cache_size` to `24M`
2. Change my.ini `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to `0`
3. Change the `hosts` file to resolve ipv6 bug..
4. Try another wamp solution
5. It seems that when I run simple query(`SELECT uid FROM users`) the phpMyAdmin return a quick respond(0.0009s)..
6. Another drupal clean installation load also slow...

Thanks,
~Almog

* *I also tried UniformServer and it still slow, and changing the my.ini follwing the posts over here(stackexchange websites) and follwing drupal.org*
** *It's seems that wordpress load fast, so it seems that the problem is with the drupal only?*

Comment: There are a number of Drupal Performance related inquiries on the [Drupal stackexchange](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) that might be of interest to people reading this thread.  See [Why is Drupal so Slow?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow) or the [Performance tagged questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance?sort=votes&pagesize=50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for now:

1. Remove every WAMP service
2. ReInstall & configure last version of EasyPHP (enable only neccary php plugins!)
3. Install the lastest "EasyPHP components"
4. ***fixing the php.ini for the newst components dir in some places(like xdebug)***
5. Increasing memory_limit
6. clear all caches(browser&drupal)
7. using minified jquery by drupal(admin->performance)
8. fully restart of my pc and remove some softwares from autostart

Now it run much better! not perfect.. but it mainly because I want drupal in deploy mode!

**the deafults setting of EasyPHP is well-done! there is not much to change! **

Comment: the best solution was just **Moving to Ubuntu!**

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways:

1) Tune your installation: install php-apc, install monitoring software ([sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)) to detect bottleneck, install xdebug, [Wincachegrind](http://drupal.org/node/549700) etc.

2) Use some preconfigured software: [acquia](https://www.acquia.com/downloads), [vagrant](http://drupal.org/project/vagrant)

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 solutions to handle Drupal’s slowness on windows machine:

**1. Hosts file Settings**

Make following changes in your hosts file…

i. Call the apache web server address by ip address. On a local computer it is 127.0.0.1

ii. Comment ::1 localhost line in hosts file which is a mapping in TCP/IP v6 protocol

**2. Disable/Adjust TCP/IP v6 protocol of your network interface**

There are two options…

i. Disable TCP/IP v6 protocol of your network interface so that windows doesn’t try to resolve your hostname to an ipv6 address.

ii. ipv6 does not need to be disabled. Open your command prompt as an administrator and use following commands in command prompt

```
netsh
interface
portproxy
add v6tov4 listenport=80 connectport=80
```

80 is your web server port of course

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has always run slowly for me when hosted on Windows.  I've tried xampp, bare bones apache/php/mysql installs, and zend server.  32 or 64 bit doesn't seem to matter for speed, but 32 bit builds seem a bit more available.  So far zend seems a little better, but not as fast as a real linux server.  Have you tried VirtualBox with Ubuntu or other Linux?  I've run an Ubuntu server with 8GB of ram in my office and it was as fast as a decent VPS server.  I suggest trying that if you haven't already.

Comment: I have been tried to run it over ubuntu linux virtaul machine(virtualbox)..
After serveral hours, I've been configure it to my shared folder(host-machine) and dump the db..
but...

It even much more slower!

Comment: virtual box is always slow. why not try it on a separate ubuntu installation? OR you can use XAMPP on windows..

Answer (score 0):

Everyone knows slow websites are bad for business and your website users. However, solving the problem can be challenging, slow to implement, and often requires starting from scratch.

I am using wamp server for my drupal projects on windows7 OS. It works very much well. Its all depends how did you configured your project. I am not using any caching technique for my project. The system is having 1 million users. I did database tuning for that so It loads data very fast.

For your application I would recommand you some stuff to do

- Performance Module settings and how they work
- Caching - biggest gainer and how to implement Boost
- Other quick hits: off loading search, tweaking settings & why
  running crons is important
- Ask your host about APC and how to make sure its set up correctly
- Dare look at the database? Easy changes that will help a lot!
- Monitoring Best practices - what to set up to make sure you know what
  is going on with your server

Answer (score 0):

Try running another bare bones Drupal installation to see if the problem is with that particular site or your Development setup.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post but I've just gone through this same struggle.

I've had a very slow Drupal 7 install on Windows 7 64bit virtual machine.  I reliably had 20 second page load times.  I struggled for a while and tried:

- disabling IPv6
- adjusting local host file settings
- increasing memory limits
- As my localhost is a development machine I didn't want to have caching and opcode caching enabled all of the time, although I did try this.

In the end the Host file changes made some difference but the main issue turned out to be the Drupal CRON.

As it turns out, because I was copying down my production installation to work on locally, the CRON wasn't able to do what it was supposed to when it ran locally.  Therefore it never completed execution successfully.

Because the attempt failed, each new request would try to run the CRON again, hence the 20 second page execution times.

You can disable cron (e.g., at Administration > Configuration > System > Cron (admin/config/system/cron), by setting the "Run cron every" value to "Never".

See here for more: https://www.drupal.org/cron